# I have a Query in WAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I INSTALL WAMPSERVER in windows 7 after installation i open   phpMyAdmin it ask user name and password.

I did't use WAMP server before this is the 1st time. And thee default user name and password for this?

Comment: As it asks Username when it is installed, mostly we use Username: root Password is blank

Answer (score 1):

Change the database config values in your config.default.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_Password';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably like this:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
Username: root
Password:
```

Password is blank(no password set).
You can also add to your `C:\wamp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php` file this line: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;`